# Wagtail Custom Pages?

Tags: wagtail

I'm totally new to Wagtail/ Django.

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

I'd like to have an ability in the backend of my Wagtail CMS install to create 'pages' or 'posts' that follow a strict template.

The template would have custom fields like 'header' and aim content' etc.

I'm sure that this is possible, I'd just be interested to know how I'd go about achieving this?

For example, does anyone know if Wagtail has a plugin or other to enable this?

Thanks for all help/ direction.

Comment: Dont understand what do you mean, have you looked at the docs? http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/getting_started/tutorial.html

Comment: What you're describing sounds like exactly how Wagtail works as standard, as described in the tutorial. Or are you looking for a way to define new page types within the Wagtail admin itself, rather than in Python code? Wagtail deliberately _doesn't_ support this - see http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/getting_started/the_zen_of_wagtail.html#the-best-user-interface-for-a-programmer-is-usually-a-programming-language.

Comment: thanks @Alexey - I'm coming from a WordPress background so I'm trying to get my head around how the CMS works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create pages and posts that follow a strict template: that's exactly what Django and Wagtail let you do. But there's one catch: Wagtail takes this a step further and lets you move entire sections of a page — these are called Streamfields. It's an amazing feature, to be honest.

Here's an example to get you started (note: this is untested and not linted)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Basic Page model."""
from django.db import models

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.core.models import Page

from your_custom_app.streams import streamfields


class BasicPage(Page):
    """A basic page class."""

    template = "templates/pages/basic_page.html"
    parent_page_type = ["pages.HomePage", "pages.BasicPage"]
    subpage_types = ["pages.BasicPage"]

    header = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = StreamField(
        ('streamfield_name', streamfields.CustomStreamfield()),
        # ... More streams 
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    # Other additional fields you want on your page.

    # Panels are how you lay out your pages in the /admin/
    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel("title", classname="full title"),
        FieldPanel("header"),
        # FieldPanel("other_fields"),
        StreamFieldPanel("content"),
    ]
    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [] # Custom settings panel
    promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [] # Custom promote panel

    class Meta:
        """Meta information."""

        verbose_name = "Basic Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Basic Pages"
```

You can also download and setup [the Wagtail Bakery Demo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo), it has a lot of great examples in it.